# Position a view relative to the bottom of the safe area programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I have a view that pops up from the bottom of the screen, and is loaded in my app delegate. The problem I am having is that I cannot set the y coordinate of the view so it will appear in the same position on all screen sizes. In my case, I am trying to get this popup view to appear just above the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

This is my code, where I am placing the view relative to [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds], but it is not consistent across all screen sizes.  How can I get the coordinate I need so I can position this view in the same spot vertically on all screens?

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    UIInterfaceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:.25
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             self->popcontroller.frame = CGRectMake(0,y -90, screenWidth, 40);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:.25
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             self->popcontroller.frame = CGRectMake(0,y -120, screenWidth, 40);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
    }

    brsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (brsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (![[appDelegate window].subviews containsObject:popcontroller])
    {  [[appDelegate window] addSubview:popcontroller];

    [popcontroller setNeedsDisplay];
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to detect the extra spacing for the edge insets, there is a property on all views called `safeAreaInsets`. This can be used to detect if you need to add extra value to the layout params (top/bottom or left/right).

So in order to get your "extra margins", you can check the top/bottom value of that inset if the app is in portrait, or the "left/right" value of the insets if the app is in landscape.

One thing to be careful with, this `safeAreaInset` is set by default on the controller's root view, so if you have a custom view added as a subview, that custom view most likely won't have this property set correctly.

And to be more specific, in your case, the "frame" code would look something like

```
if deviceIsInPortrait {
   let frame = CGRect(x:thisX,
                      y: -90 - self.view.safeAreaInsets.top // this will be 0 for non "notch" phones
                      width: myWidth
                      height: myHeight
}
else {
  let frame = CGRect(x:thisX,
                      y: -90 - self.view.safeAreaInsets.left // this will be 0 for non "notch" phones
                      width: myWidth
                      height: myHeight
}
```

Also one more piece of advice, use auto-layout as often as possible.

Comment: Thanks! safeAreaInserts was exactly what I needed and your example worked for me perfectly.